# Memory not being properly detected

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

I purchased a Crucial 4GBx2 kit and recently installed the two sticks.  One stick was detected, while the other was not.  I tried reseating and moving the stick, however, the stick was still not detected.  I tested the slots using the other new stick, and it worked fine.  Next, I booted into Windows just to confirm, and only the additional 4GB was detected (12 GB including my previous 8 GB that was already installed).

However, when looking at CPU-Z, it reads that the Memory Size is 16GB.  After seeing this, I went back to my BIOS, and looked at the information for each slot.  The BIOS actually seems to be detecting the memory in the slot, however, no information is listed for the Manufacturer or Module Size like the other stick.

[image: BIOS]

I have yet to run MemTest, but will do so when I get the chance.

The memory is the same speed as the old, and I used the Crucial scanner to confirm it was a good match.

Motherboard is an Asus X99-A.  I have also updated the BIOS to the latest version.

Comment: what is your motherboard model?

Comment: Sorry, forgot I didn't include that.  Asus X99-A.

Comment: So you have tried the stick in other slots and it still did not show up?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Yes, I have tried the stick in all the other available slots, and had no luck.  Tried the working stick in them as well, worked fine in them all.

Comment: It could possibly be defected. Its possible to show up reading what it should be but it doesn't seem to be working.  Do you have a friend or another machine you could test it on?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin That was the conclusion that I came to, but wanted to get any other ideas before contacting Crucial about it.  Being in Japan, I'm a bit weary about going through the return process.  No friends that I can have test it at the moment, but I could try later.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the second stick work on its own?

Comment: @Paul The working stick or the non working one?  Unfortunately, my original sticks are now blocked by the heatsink, so I have not attempted to remove them to test.  However, the new working stick works fine with or without the nonworking stick.  The non working stick does not work in any configuration.